# Why is the background image not showing?

Tags: css, html, image, background, banner

**Background image is not showing for the banner, but I'm pretty sure my code is correct.**

I'm trying to put a background image as a banner on my index page, which will have text over the top. I'm following a tutorial on YouTube (I know, I'm sorry) and I'm pretty sure that I've followed the example code perfectly (I will change it eventually but I just wanted a reference).

```
<main>
  <section class="index-banner">
    <h2>FILM. MODELING.<br>DESIGN.</h2>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tellus velit, blandit ut nisi in.</h1>
  </section>
</main>

.index-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('img/tom.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I should be getting a background image behind my `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags, but I'm not seeing anything. I tried removing the formatting but that's still not sorting it.

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct? Have you checked the dev tools console for errors?

Comment: index.html is in the root folder. The image path is rootfolder/img/tom.jpg

Comment: Code seems fine to me (with a proper path and image): https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p1k4uemz/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was actually in a meta tag. Where I had...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
```

...there was a space after the 1.0 still within the "". This obviously created the image issue.